# Really weird question about unit analysis

Tags: si-units, unit-conversion

Hi guys this is quite an interesting question I have because there appears to be two correct answers.

There is an equation described by: 
$$
Pt = mC_\mathrm{mass}T+m_\mathrm{water}C_\mathrm{water}T+K,
$$
where $t$ is time, $P$ is power, $T$ is temperature change, $K$ is a constant, and the $C$s are the specific heat capacity of either the water or the mass. The details about the experiment are not worth talking about. My problem comes when I try to find the unit of $K$.

Here is my logic. If I'm gonna plot $t$ against mass $m$ of the "mass" then:

- my gradient will be $(C_\mathrm{mass}T)/P$;
- my $y$ intercept will be $(m_\mathrm{water}C_\mathrm{water}T+K)/P$; and
- my $y$ intercept will pass through the $y$ axis therefore will be in units of seconds only.

This is where I trip up bigtime. As I calculate things, you have
$$
{\rm time} = \frac{{\rm (mass) (specific\ heat) (temperature)}+K}{\rm power}
$$
so therefore
$$
{\rm power\times time}= {\rm (mass) (specific\ heat) (temperature)}+K
$$
or in other words
$$
\rm{\frac{work}{time}\times\frac{time}{1}} = \rm{\frac{mass}{1}\frac{work}{mass\times temperature}\times\frac{temperature}{1}} +K,
$$
i.e. ${\rm work} = {\rm work}+K$.

> [image]

As you can see I get to the point: $\rm joules=joules+unknown\ unit$.

Therefore the unknown units can either be unitless or be in joules. It is impossible as far as I can see to make a claim one way or the other?

Comment: Unitless means "units of 1". You can't add something in joules to something in "units of 1".

Comment: I have turned your mathematical formulae into LaTeX notation; you're expected to do this yourself in future posts on this site. A good tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your original equation $K$ is a summand in a combination that gives the work $Pt$, it must have dimension of energy and units in joules.

Moreover, there is no real support in your calculations for the notion that $K$ would be unitless ─ it's entirely unclear why you think that that would even be an option.

Comment: I was going along the lines of "since it is unitless it won't contribute to the units on the LHS" in other words, as a constant it won't contribute. Joules plus an arbitrary constant is still joules. So it could still be an option?

Comment: Joules plus anything that's not joules (or commensurate to joules) is meaningless and undefined. You **cannot** add, compare (as in, greater than or less than) or set as equal two quantities with different units. That should be engraved on the inside of your skull ;-).

Comment: Yep gonna chisel that into my head right now, by the way thank you so much for helping me